# How can I get return value from A class to class B in python?

Tags: python, django

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):ㅤ
    attachment = forms.FileField()


class View1(FormView):
    template_name = 'main.html'
    form_class = InputForm

    def post(self, request) :
        I_want_this_file = request.FILES.get('attachment')
        return I_want_this_file

class View2:
    blar blar .....
```

When there's this structure,

Is there any way to get the value of I_want_this_file from a class called View2?

I understand that I have to hand over the parameters to get the return value.

But I couldn't bring it because of the "request".

When a user uploads a file from a template called main.html,
I want to take the file itself, put it in the return value I_want_this_file,
and bring the file itself to View2.

I have to bring that, but it's not my personal project, so there's no other way to add a file field than this.

I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Is the `View2` class something that you are writing yourself, or is that also from someone else's package?

Comment: I think you need to redirect the file name or something as url param to the url of `View2` in `post` method of `View1`. Also see how do I ask a good question [ask] and how to make [repro]

Comment: @MattPitkin Someone else's package

Comment: Unless you can edit the `View2` class, or it already has a method/attribute that you can set to pass it the file name, then I don't think you'll be able to what you want. Is there documentation for the package you're using to show what `View2` can do? Or, do you have access to the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Is the following code what you need?

```py
class InputForm(forms.Form):ㅤ
    attachment = forms.FileField()


class View1(FormView):
    template_name = 'main.html'
    form_class = InputForm

    def post(self, request) :
        I_want_this_file = request.FILES.get('attachment')
        return I_want_this_file

class View2:
    View1 = View1()
    I_want_this_file = View1.post(request)
```

If not, feel free to give me a feedback, and I'll edit my answer.